# Pan, Rotate and Zoom with MapKit / MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

First attempt at a MapKit / CoreLocation Swift-based iOS app. And obviously, the difficulty seems to go off the charts with first issue!

The app is focused around the golf course. So I would like to be able to select a hole on the course, and the map will pan, zoom & rotate so that:

- the teebox is at the middle & bottom of the visible screen
- the green is at the middle & top of the visible screen
- the compass should be displayed to help the user with orientation

Obviously, every hole is a different size, shape and orientation.

I have used Google Maps to obtain some coordinates, and have the current [basic] code:

```
@IBAction func buttonHole10Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {

let hole10nw = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.873931, longitude: -1.482514)
let hole10sw = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.870293, longitude: -1.480026)
let hole10se = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.870341, longitude: -1.479719)
let hole10ne = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.874079, longitude: -1.481551)

let hole10Rect = createMKMapRect(nw: hole10nw, se: hole10se)
let hole10Bearing = getBearing(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.870363, longitude: -1.479884), to: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53.874023, longitude: -1.482110))
print("bearing: \(hole10Bearing), \(360+hole10Bearing)") // = -19, rather than 360-19 = 340 degrees...

mapView.camera.heading = 360 + hole10Bearing
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(hole10Rect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10), animated: false)
}



func createMKMapRect(nw: CLLocationCoordinate2D, se: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKMapRect {
    let nwPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(nw)
    let nwRect = MKMapRectMake(nwPoint.x, nwPoint.y, 0, 0)

    let sePoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(se)
    let seRect = MKMapRectMake(sePoint.x, sePoint.y, 0, 0)

    let rect = MKMapRectUnion(nwRect, seRect)
    return rect
}

func getBearing(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {

    let fromLat = degreesToRadians(degrees: from.latitude)
    let fromLon = degreesToRadians(degrees: from.longitude)

    let toLat = degreesToRadians(degrees: to.latitude);
    let toLon = degreesToRadians(degrees: to.longitude);

    let deltaLon = toLon - fromLon;

    let y = sin(deltaLon) * cos(toLat);
    let x = cos(fromLat) * sin(toLat) - sin(fromLat) * cos(toLat) * cos(deltaLon);
    let radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

    return radiansToDegrees(radians: radiansBearing)
}

func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double { return degrees * Double.pi / 180.0 }

func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double { return radians * 180.0 / Double.pi }
```

I hope this image shows what I am trying to achieve... It is currently getting the red box, but I would like to get the green box.

[image: Golf Hole]

Comment: For testing purposes, I currently have 2 `UIButton`'s to move between 2 holes, with the above code defined for both holes with appropriate coordinates. I _accidentally_ pressed 1 button twice, and this actually corrects the orientation / rotation after the 2nd button press?!?!

Comment: Can you post the code for your buttons?

Comment: @Jake, apologies, the top section of code was inside the IBAction function and I did not include this wrapper. But this could be in viewDidLoad(), etc. I am doing manual testing at this stage.